# Enable edit mode in datagridview only for certain column c#

Tags: c#, ms-access, datagridview

How do i enable edit mode only for the certain column?

Let's say i have this columns:

`Product Code || Quantity || Description || Price`

I wanted to enable edit mode only for `Quantity` column and `Price` column. The rest cannot be edited.

I already did this below code, but it seems not working:

```
dataGridView1.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnKeystroke;
dataGridView1.Columns["Quantity"].ReadOnly = false;
dataGridView1.Columns["Price"].ReadOnly = false;
```

All i can do is disable `ReadOnly` to `false`, but it is enabled all of the columns that i don't want to enable them.

Note: By the time program runs for the first time, i already set the `ReadOnly` to `true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will help you

[MSDN DataGridViewColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cze614bb%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

The out-of-box solution is using attributes on your data model:

```
public class MyDataModel
{
    // Do not show in data grid view
    [System.ComponentModel.Browsable(false)]
    public virtual int ID { get; protected set; }

    // Set to read-only in data grid view
    [System.ComponentModel.ReadOnly(true)]
    public virtual string Person { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set ReadOnly = true to all non-editable column.
By default, column are set to ReadOnly = false

Comment: yes, i already did that. By the time program runs, i set the `ReadOnly` to `true`. But it is still cannot

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn dc in dgvTestParameter.Columns)
        {
            if (dc.Index.Equals(0) || dc.Index.Equals(4))
            {
                dc.ReadOnly = false;
            }
            else
            {
                dc.ReadOnly = true;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int EditableCol_index = datagridview["colname"].index;

// if this is true , you wont be able to edit even you set the column readonly=false;
datagridview1.readonly = false;
foreach (datagridviewcolumns c in datagridview1 )
{
   c.readonly = true;
   if( c.index == EditableCol_index )
   { 
     c.readonly = false;  // editable
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From design part you just check "Enable Editing" mode in your Datagridview.
this example may help you,

[image]

I have added two columns on as readonly purpose(column name is "ReadOnly Column") and another as editable column(column name is "Normal Column").

Code:

```
dataGridView1.Columns["readOnlyColumn"].ReadOnly = true;
```

Thank you....